Image Preview with Bootstrap, HTML + JS
I am attempting to make a system that allows the user to upload an image and then it will replace the already placeholder image with the uploaded image by the user, I have attempted the JavaScript code below, but it simply just does not display the image when I upload it, the website shows the uploaded image.
I have used Bootstrap to style my columns and make my image fluid.
Below is the block of code relating to my issue
 </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="input-group mb-3" style="width: 40%;">
        <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupFile01" id="uploader">Upload</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="inputGroupFile01" id="inputimg">
        <img src="profile.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
      </div>      
  </div>

HTML CODE ABOVE
JS CODE BELOW
document.getElementById('uploader').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            document.getElementById('inputimg').src = e.target.result;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
});

Tried the JS code embedded above, I expected the placeholder image to be replaced by the image I uploaded, that did not happen and nothing actually happened

these two clauses seem to contradict one another: it simply just does not display the image when I upload it, the website shows the uploaded image.; can you elaborate? Also, your file input has two ids, which is invalid.

Typo?  You're listening for the change event of a <label> element.  In general it looks like you just need to examine your id values in the code, and have confused yourself about which is which.

Have you tried with document.getElementById('inputGroupFile01').addEventListener('change', function(event) {/*...*/}); ?

@mykaf when i upload the image, it shows the url of the image in the upload file box, but doesnt show the actual image still showing the placeholder jpg

Yep, got my ID wrong in JS. Fixed it and now it functions properly.

@DM23545 written an answer accordingly

The solution is to add the event to the input rather than the label, like
document.getElementById('inputGroupFile01').addEventListener('change', function(event) {/*...*/});

